# network access through proxy server with virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, proxy-server, ubuntu-14.10

In the company that I work, we have Windows 7 installed on all PCs. We don't have internet access through Windows but can set proxy settings in Firefox and can thus access the Internet.

I installed a virtual box on one of these Windows 7 machines and Ubuntu 14.10 but I have problem with accessing the Internet.

How can I access the Internet through the proxy server via an Ubuntu virtual box running under Windows 7?

Answer (score 4):

you have to make a Network Bridge in Windows (between VBox Host-Only Network and the Controller connected to the Internet)

In Virtualbox you can leave the Adapter at NAT

I´m using this with my debian-vm. Additionally I added the Network-Proxy as system-wide Proxy in my VM.

Good Luck!

Comment: there are no details here

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Bridged network mode on your virtual box. Then assign IP address for you ubuntu to connect to your network, and then use the proxy setting at the ubuntu's internet browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the proxy for the console:

```
$export http_proxy=http://[ipproxy]:[port]
```

on firefox you can set the proxy in the network settings.

Comment: That would be `export` instead of `echo`

Answer (score 0):

```
$export http_proxy=http://[ipproxy]:[port]
```

this is works for me in solaris
network setting is in bridge

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).